# Starting a single Spark Slave (or Worker)

Tags: apache-spark

When I do this

```
spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4% sbin/start-slave.sh
```

I get this message

```
failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker:
                         Default is conf/spark-defaults.conf.
```

Even though I have this:

```
spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4% ll conf | grep spark-defaults.conf
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 xxxx.xxxxx ama-unix  507 Apr 29 07:09 spark-defaults.conf
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 xxxx.xxxxx ama-unix  507 Apr 13 12:06 spark-defaults.conf.template
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: I think both slaves and workers are two different things, worker means a  system, and slave means executor. number of executers (slaves) can run inside the worker node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should make sure you are using the command correctly,

```
Usage: start-slave.sh <worker#> <spark-master-URL>
```

where `<worker#>` is worker number you want to launch on the machine which you are running this script.
`<spark-master-URL>` is like `spark://localhost:7077`

Comment: Thanks, yes i was aware of the worker#, but why do i need to specify spark url if specified in spark-defaults.conf?

Comment: @jakstack, which version of spark are you using? I cannot start slave unless a master-url was given, just because in spark 1.3.1, it will check arguments number first.

Comment: thanks, I'm using 1.3.0, does what you suggest apply to this version as well?

Comment: @jakstack, I suppose yes, have you try to add masterURL and does it work?

Comment: Yes when I supply worker# and the master url it works fine, but I'm thinking what's the point behind having spark-default.conf file

Comment: in my case I had left out the worker number and that was the reason it didn't start (v 1.4.1). thanks Shen.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using spark 1.6.1, and you no longer need to indicate a worker number, so the actual usage is:

```
start-slave.sh spark://<master>:<port>
```

Comment: This note was a lifesaver.  I have been debugging for days now, relying off of a pattern start up script that I (and collaborators) had used about a year and a half ago.